# Selenium: Can't find an element in HTML

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hi I am working on the script to automate downloads of videos from this side https://pixabay.com/videos/
I can find a class with href(href is an attribute with URL) but after that Selenium gives me a bug with any error only a result of print(xy.get_atribute("href)) is None:
my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import requests
import time
tag = "city "
while True:
    s = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)
    driver.minimize_window()
    
    tester = tag.split()
    print(tester)
    print(len(tester))
    if len(tester) == 2:
        tag = tester[0] + "%20" + tester[1]
        print(tag)
    print("2 " + tag)
    driver.get("https://pixabay.com/cs/videos/search/" + tag )
    images = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'item' )
    print(images)
    n = 0
    lenght = 0
    

    for image in images:
        image = image.get_attribute("href")
        print(image)
    break
```

HTML on the side

```
<html lang="cs" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>.</head> <body class="" data-new-gr-C-5-check-loaded="14.1050." data-gr-ext-installed>
<noscript>_</noscript> <div id="wrapper"> > <div id="header">...</div> <div id="content" class="clearfix">
::before <div id="search-term" style="display:none">city</div> <div class="media_list">
<div style="border-bottom:1px solid #f0f1f4"> </div> <div style="background:#e8eaec" class="external-media">.</div> <div style="background: #f6f5fa"> <div style="max-width: 1824px;padding: 10px 3px 20px;margin: auto">
<h1 style="font-size: 13px;color:#bbb;margin:0 19px; position:relative;top:2px">70 videa zdarma z city</h1> <div class="related-keywords">...</div> <div class="row-masonry video video-search-results"> flex <div class="row-masonry-cell" style="flex-basis: 355.55555555555554px; flex-grow: 1.7777777777777777; flex-shrink: 1.7777777777777777; max-width: 622.2222222222222px"> <div class="row-masonry-cell-outer" style="padding-top: 56.25%"> <div class="row-masonry-cell-inner"> <div itemscope itemtype="schema.org/videoobject" class="item" data-w="1920" data-h="1980">
<meta itemprop="license" content="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain/"> <meta itemprop="contentUrl" content="//player.vimeo.com/external/142621375.mobile.mp4?s=e9a3c9616798b6f3de74d579ea8314acc75fad72&profile_id=116"> <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/539965294-5d28c2680682aa5173e86fa74acb94671783ba7e2dc2892682e897c8a158af75-d_640x360.jpg"> <meta itemprop="name" content="New York City, Manhattan, Lidé"> <meta itemprop="description" content="New York City, Manhattan, Lidé, Auta, Rozcestí, Amerika"> <meta itemprop="duration" content="TM145"> <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2022-02-16"> <a href="/cs/videos/new-york-city-manhattan-lidC3%A9-auta-1944/"> == $ <div class="media" data-mp4="//player.vimeo.com/external/142621375.mobile.mp4?s=e9a3c9616798b6f3de74d579ea8314acc75fad72&profile_id=116">
<img class="video-preview" src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/539965294-5d28c26...d 640x360.jpg" alt="New York City, Manhattan, Lidé, Auta">
<i></i> </div> </a> ►<em class="info-corner">-</em>
<em class="info-line">-</em> flex </div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: What does `https://pixabay.com/cs/videos/search/" + tag` resolves to?

Comment: So this is only one module of my bigger project end after a finished this module I will import a tag from another module and in this module is tog only for development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the values of the *href* attributes you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://pixabay.com/videos/search/madona/")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item>a")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://pixabay.com/videos/search/madona/")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item']/a")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fthe-blessed-virgin-mary-in-front-of-the-roman-catholic-diocese-public-place-in-gm1297534089-390641862%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=96d4db58e5ed4dfa33719b6789ec2e54c6a9e93c', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fshining-star-landscape-above-the-nativity-scene-in-bethlehem-in-the-middle-of-the-gm1284414826-381542953%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=63c5e9d5424c6ed9234b7558a47c2f9bd34b0b2f', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fvirgin-mary-statue-and-stained-glass-window-cathedral-la-major-marseille-france-gm523679382-92792807%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=eba8300b6dc8d879d5c0c20ad4159667075b13a8', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fmary-and-joseph-kissing-and-touching-baby-jesus-gm1331078248-414315796%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=0d8025f74d6831ec1728a487c6c348fbb0489c0e', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fthe-blessed-virgin-mary-in-front-of-the-roman-catholic-diocese-public-place-in-gm1297536160-390641882%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=1a8d9dc7db4a76fe4fe8b15d050e950a4ef6ceee', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fmary-and-joseph-speaking-and-taking-care-of-baby-jesus-gm1331074139-414312596%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=71968733d6752db862f8f614ec81965c72c045c7', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fvirgin-mary-over-the-village-of-maaloula-in-syria-view-of-the-virgin-mary-in-the-gm1225424859-360681300%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=77ee3cc8968570cce77488fd36324f9a21aa8cdb', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fstatue-of-st-mary-in-the-church-gm1192697685-338971692%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=0bc49cf096c333282f735ce562f59c9eb17309f4', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fnotre-dame-de-paris-exterior-beautiful-statue-of-virgin-and-child-architecture-gm980707058-266394749%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=69ab20290bfcaef4b644d7f888618d569cd0c994', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fmary-and-joseph-with-baby-jesus-in-barn-gm1331079736-414317051%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=dbae2b824a22623d12eaf1127f0fd33f4de2cc41', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fchristmas-nativity-gm113747428-13537033%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=496f4633dd6cd6394f1a06959e4c6dd089d3aeff', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fsculpture-of-the-image-of-nossa-senhora-aparecida-the-patroness-of-brazil-gm1348138435-425434800%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=c745fbc9d7b69eeaa2186c9843f8d566590b5e61', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fchurch-icon-close-up-gm824010680-134889129%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=89a9e0bee0d8d49c4dad52407e63e5ab37a98b55', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fangled-detail-of-icon-image-of-virgin-mary-in-st-nicholas-orthodox-cathedral-in-nice-gm860958856-143133885%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=0fc269e8cf9d4fc2c0a6384537349b33fa98f963', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fvitaleta-chapel-aerial-view-in-the-wonderful-valley-of-orcia-tuscany-la-toscana-drone-gm1309396875-399121012%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=356539420e275a4aae53df6dfc2ec1e22a469f5a', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fburning-candles-in-the-cathedral-of-chartres-gm1358325815-431987333%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=3e6b1cd3f8922c80cb2ea4aacbc5f0ca13b48024', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Flourdes-france-sanctuary-of-our-lady-of-lourdes-a-famous-pilgrimage-place-gm1352878773-428151138%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=e29f6ee34464b11218e1bba7f72d321db571968a', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fsanctuary-of-our-lady-of-lourdes-gm1348213795-425484844%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=00fc1155414568f9c01d4d8e07b3e7d6396e9c76', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Frosaries-on-the-bridge-in-lourdes-gm1348213738-425484842%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=ffc4132d8125f9da46baff336297150fee0617e2', 'https://pixabay.com/link/?ua=t%3Devent%26ec%3Dapi_ad%26ea%3Dnavigate%26el%3Dgetty%26v%3D1%26tid%3DUA-20223345-1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.istockphoto.com%2Fvideo%2Fa-statue-of-the-virgin-mary-in-lourdes-gm1348213561-425484841%3Futm_source%3Dpixabay%26utm_medium%3Daffiliate%26utm_campaign%3DSRP_video_sponsored%26utm_content%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpixabay.com%252Fvideos%252Fsearch%252Fmadona%252F%26utm_term%3Dmadona&hash=198c52a01d8f0d8e2c2079ea5238cfc1f3da8d00']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I think OP was trying for _`get_attribute("href")`_, am I missing something?

Comment: I now I can got a video URL

Comment: @undetectedSelenium no.... disregard my previous comment.

Comment: You want to wait for a `div.item > a[href]` -> it's important that the href is there because that's what's causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you haven't actually provided what the error is, which would be helpful.

Additionally, your for loop is overwriting the `image` var which is just bad practice, but shouldn't break anything.

Finally, it looks like you've written an infinite loop with a non-conditional break at the end and no `continue`. Is this supposed to be a loop?

Comment: OK, I am sorry but I do not know how to copy a code from inspecting part of the browser so I do that with print screen and after that, I will put it into an AI image to text convertor and I have not any error only a bug with a href. Href should be a "/videos/seoul-city-streets-road-night-view-21985/. But It is a None now and this is wrong